# How to extract email body using the google app engine mail api?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have an email that looks like this after I extract the body using the mail_message.body() function:

```
From nobody Sat Mar 29 12:59:23 2014
content-transfer-encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

test name
```

Is there an easy way to strip the header lines? I just want to extract "test name" and whatever else is after that in the email body. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the headers are separated with body by two newlines. So you can use this where it is replacing everything before the first two newlines.

```
body = re.sub("^[\s\S]*?[\n\r][\n\r]", "", body)
```